# breaker size for 600' run using #4 wire

Tags: wiring

I am trying to find out what breaker size to use for a 600' run to my wellpump(2 horse)------I am using #4 wire-also do I need breakers at both ends-maybe one in the middle??   thanks

Comment: What voltage is the pump?  Do you know the amp usage rather than just "2 horsepower" ?  The size of the load should dictate the wire and breaker size.

Comment: at that distance we would want to take voltage drop so we need voltage of the pump and the FLA (amprage) some 2 horse pumps draw much more when they have a big head to push VS a shallow well pump and that will affect the drop at 600' no bkr in the middle one at the panel you are feeding from and a disconect at the pump, or another small 220/110 panel

Comment: It sounds like what you need is an electrician, or a much better grasp of how electricity works before you bite off doing your own. Aside from distance to well and amperage/voltage of pump, distance down the well and what wire is used there also matters. Copper .vs. aluminum also comes into play, and aluminum is often a better deal for this length of run.

Comment: took me a minute to find the voltage drop formula ulglys page 52 VD=2K x L x I/CM    copper K value is  12.9  aluminum K value is 21.2  A standard pump 2 hp 115V would draw 24 amps , 230V would draw 12Amps

Answer (score 1):

To answer the OP's question:

No you only need one breaker where the conductors recieve their supply. (At the main panel). The breaker needs to be sized the protect the conductors the well pump should have internal protection for the motor.

You didn't say whether your #4 was copper or aluminum. It makes a big difference. I will do both calculations with Ed Beal's numbers for the K factors (I usually use 10.4 for copper and 17.0 for aluminum which would yield smaller wires but warm wire has a higher K factor so I will use the hire numbers.)

A 2 hp 230 volt motor draws 12 amps according to the NEC. Using the voltage drop formula solved for area in circular mils. Acm= K x I x 2L /VD
With a 3% voltage drop the recommended number from the NEC yields 25,800 cm for copper which is a little smaller than #6 at 26,240 cm. so if you have #4 copper you have plenty of wire.

However the same calculation with aluminum yields 42,400 and #4 is 41,740 so you would actually need #2 if it is aluminum.

Voltage drops are recommendations from the National Electrical Code and are not an enforceable part of the code. Voltage drop calculations are performed with full load running currents not with startup currents. They recommend 3% for a branch circuit or feeder and 5% total between the two. Since this is a branch circuit the recommended amount is 3% or 7.2 volts.

tl;dr You are good with #4 copper wire. The breaker size depends on the manufacturers recommendation for your well pump, or I need to know if you are using an inverse time breaker or instantaneous trip.

Comment: I like your good clear answer.  One question:  "The breaker needs to be sized the protect the conductors."   What about NEC Table 430.52?  Do you not agree that breaker size for a motor branch circuit is limited based on motor full load current (250% in the case of an inverse time breaker)?

Comment: Yes I agree with you. That is to protect the conductors and still allow the motor to start without nuisance tripping. If you had a non-motor load you don't get to go that high. You cite the correct table for sizing a motor load OCPD. The OCPD is there to protect the conductors. The overloads protect the motor.

Comment: In OP's example, a 12 FLA motor would have not larger than a 30 A breaker (250% per NEC 430.52), whereas #4 Cu wire might otherwise have a 60A breaker.  Is it not correct that the breaker is not sized on behalf of the conductor in this case?

Comment: Hmm I see what you are saying. The NEC always require a minimum. You can usually (with some exceptions) use a larger conductor if you like. Especially in the case of voltage drop compensation we routinely upsize the conductors without upsizing the breaker. So in this case you are correct in saying an inverse time breaker would max out at 30 amps even though the wire is good for more. Since the breaker is smaller than the wires capacity, it definitely protects the conductors. According to table 310.15(B)(16) #4 copper could be protected at 70 amps for 60° wire in a non-motor circuit.

Comment: @OSX - I do see that table says 70 amps and I do understand why conductors must be upsized to compensate for voltage drop (I am not sure the NEC is as strict or straightforward on voltage drop calculations as is being implied here, but I do like your method).,  I also understand *motor protection* is separate from *branch protection.* My point is, *in the case of motor loads why does NEC limit OCPD to a smaller size than the conductor will allow?*  Are you saying this is an idiosyncrasy of the way the code is written?  Somehow I doubt that.

Comment: @OSX - I posted a StackExchange question on this to get it out of comments.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

took me a minute to find the voltage drop formula ulglys page 50 VD=2K x L x I/CM    copper K value is  12.9  aluminum K value is 21.2  A standard pump 2 hp 115V would draw 24 amps , 230V would draw 12Amps both valuse from uglys
:  doing at 230V as that is a long 115v  run. the VD on copper 4.4V you could have safely dropped ~7V and been within code (p.s. CM for #4 copper is 41740 ) so why do you want to use #4 wire you could use much smaller ALuminum (I hate aluminum Except for cases like this ) but now you have all the info to recalculate #4copper wire is good for almost 70 amps when sized for a pump and aluminum is good for about 60 amps,,,, even if you have a 30Amp draw because you add some big flood lights out there you could go way smaller
the formula came from uglys 2014 electrical reference page 50

Comment: 3 % nominal 5% at end of branch 210.19 a note #4

Comment: that is why the nec requires 125% wire size, to allow for starting currents. the normal overload used in the U.S. is a class 10 these allow 115% overload for 10 seconds prior to tripping out , most of the really big systems I work on are up to speed in 1-2 seconds when line started any longer and we put them on something called a soft start that pulses to get to speed,,, I have seen motors take on chippers to take 4 seconds to start and my 600A clamp could not read what it was pulling but the wiring did not get warm after it was at speed it was running at 180A (150HP motor) and this only 24"